# Preview URL Spotify API or Lib

Tags: spotify

Is there a way to get a 30 seconds preview URL for a track in Spotify API or Lib (like Deezer API preview URL) ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Spotify doesn't have this functionality at all at the moment, so there's no API for it.