# plotGoogleMaps query for plotting maps with four columns

Tags: r

Helo All,

I am using plotGoogleMaps package for plotting piecharts on world map. segmentgooglemap is the function in this package that does this. Here is the manual http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotGoogleMaps/vignettes/plotGoogleMaps-intro.pdf. if I try to plot piechart for 3 column it works fine like given in manual for zinc, lead, copper. But if I try to plot for 4 columns it doesnot work. Can anyone guide me why it is showing so. I have tried many options but didnt succeed. Looking forward for reply.

Regards,
Gourja