# What are the alternatives to the standard C++ library and boost with a clear implementation?

Tags: c++, std

I don't have particular problems with the standard library, the only real issue is that the C++ library is used interfacing the code with a bunch of headers and the real implementation heavily depends on what my application will find on the target machine in terms of libraries.

So I was looking for libraries with containers, algorithms and iteraators, maybe open source, with a clear implementation, so far i have only found this 2:

- boost library
- QT library

But none of this is a real C++ standard library, with this I mean that QT is mainly a GUI library that *also* offers containers and other good stuff, boost is simpy huge and all the C++ std-like components are just a really small part of this library, also this library it's not really trivial to port to a new target because the build system have a non-standard toolchain and it uses its own build solution ( bjam ).

In the end with both boost and QT i don't get an easy solution or a workable solution that can replace the C++ library as i wish it would be.

So far the best project that i have found is the [Apache C++ Standard Library](http://stdcxx.apache.org/) that was just right but this project is dead.

Someone can suggest a library that just replaces the standard library and it's open-source with a permissive license ?

Comment: Still it's not clear that why the standard library can't be used ? It's standard because, all conforming implementation should provide it. Also, just imagine that if some functionality are available in `std` then why someone will take pain to again re-write/re-test everything ?

Comment: @iammilind ... so i was searching for a ready to use library :)

Comment: Ready to use for what? I can't see the need to replace the standard library, unless your compiler only provides a partial implementation.

Comment: @juanchopanza can we just talk about alternatives ? qt and boost are the first 2, what are the others ?

Answer (score 3):

> the real implementation heavily depends on what my application will
>   find on the target machine in terms of libraries

The real implementation basically depends on your compiler, not the machine you're running your programs on.

Different compilers may come with different implementations, however I believe this is no reason to replace such an extensive and well-thought out library with something home-made. That's the very reason you're unlikely to find a replacement library that is this good.

Comment: when i was talking about home-made stuff ? if this is true i can't see why QT offers its own implementation of the standard library. For example under Windows, when my program uses the Microsoft C++ library i don't think that my compiler can do something about this library and i have to stick with it.

Comment: Libraries that provide their own containers usually do it because of some unjustified fear. Those are mistakes from the past. You can safely rely on the STL implementations. By the way, there's just a handful of them in use (you can see them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library#Implementations)).

Answer (score 1):

Noone seems to understand what you want to achieve by switching to an alternative library, which is why you don't get any answers.

STL library is universally availbale on anything from toasters to supercomputers. It is also aggresively optimised to deliver the highest possible performance on the target platform.

Now, let me clarify some of your points.

P1. *"real implementation heavily depends on what my application will find on the target machine in terms of libraries"*

**Wrong**, C++ standard library is implemented on top of C standard library, both of them are supplied along with any descent compiler. Both can use system calls  to do some low level stuff, like open files, create threads etc. That's it, no other dependencies, guaranteed by standard.

Comment: Actually the standard library is _not_ available on everything from toasters to supercomputers.  It is very likely to be unavailable on many (or even most?) embedded platforms.

Comment: "everything from toasters to supercomputers" yeah sure and i can't even include sprintf because gameboys don't have a libi18n -_-