# How can I make a jar with native library in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, java.library.path

How can I make a jar with native library in Intellij IDEA? In the JVM it looks like Djava.library.path=C:\Users\User\workspace\lib\native\win

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a .jar file or export jar on IntelliJ (like eclipse java archive export)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-on-intellij-like-eclipse-java-archive-e)

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I think this question is more related to JNI than the one you linked to. Apart from that I don't really have a clue what is being asked here...

Comment: @maba Ah, I think you might be right - I thought it was about using Intellij's native libraries to create a JAR.  I agree it's not particularly clear.